# Bootstrap black boxes on dropdown

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, box

Problem:
[Black Boxes Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hP69U.png)

The Code:

```
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="header">NOTIFICATIONS</li>
                        <li class="body">
                            <ul class="menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                        <div class="icon-circle bg-light-green">
                                            <i class="material-icons">person_add</i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="menu-info">
                                            <h4>12 new members joined</h4>
                                            <p>
                                                <i class="material-icons">access_time</i> 14 mins ago
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                        <div class="icon-circle bg-cyan">
                                            <i class="material-icons">add_shopping_cart</i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="menu-info">
                                            <h4>4 sales made</h4>
                                            <p>
                                                <i class="material-icons">access_time</i> 22 mins ago
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                        <div class="icon-circle bg-red">
                                            <i class="material-icons">delete_forever</i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="menu-info">
                                            <h4><b>Nancy Doe</b> deleted account</h4>
                                            <p>
                                                <i class="material-icons">access_time</i> 3 hours ago
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                        <div class="icon-circle bg-orange">
                                            <i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="menu-info">
                                            <h4><b>Nancy</b> changed name</h4>
                                            <p>
                                                <i class="material-icons">access_time</i> 2 hours ago
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                        <div class="icon-circle bg-blue-grey">
                                            <i class="material-icons">comment</i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="menu-info">
                                            <h4><b>John</b> commented your post</h4>
                                            <p>
                                                <i class="material-icons">access_time</i> 4 hours ago
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                        <div class="icon-circle bg-light-green">
                                            <i class="material-icons">cached</i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="menu-info">
                                            <h4><b>John</b> updated status</h4>
                                            <p>
                                                <i class="material-icons">access_time</i> 3 hours ago
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                        <div class="icon-circle bg-purple">
                                            <i class="material-icons">settings</i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="menu-info">
                                            <h4>Settings updated</h4>
                                            <p>
                                                <i class="material-icons">access_time</i> Yesterday
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="footer">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">View All Notifications</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

I have tried aspect elementing and looking through the code, but have not come across the source of the black boxes.

I am using the ***AdminBSB - Material Design*** template, the problem also accures on the default notifications and task dropdowns.